# Why can't I open this object in Python?

Tags: python, spyder

I created a class called CMA. When I run the code from the main script, I am able to open it after defining it and running a function within the class, as seen in this code:

```
class CMA(object):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ... my code here...
    def RunEstimation(self):
        ...more code here...


cma = CMA()
cma.RunEstimation()
```

However, I created a wrapper function so I do not have to run these commands within the code, to avoid any unnecessary executions:

```
from CMACode import CMA
cma = CMA()
cma.RunEstimation()
```

From the printed outputs, I can see the function running as intended. The `cma` variable shows up in Spyder's Variable Explorer, however it results in an error when I open it. A difference I see is the values of the variables in the Spyder Variable Explorer. On the wrapper code, it says that `cma` 's Value is `'CMA object of CMACode module'`. Where CMACode is the folder that the py script is in. When I run the script directly, I see that the value of `cma` is `'CMa object of __main__ module'`.

Comment: So, this is a spyder question, not a python question per se. There's no concept of "opening" an object in python.

Comment: You're going to need to work harder to provide a reproducible code sample.  I don't see anything wrong with what you posted.

Comment: you need to use a `if __name__ == "__main__"`   block in your module with the class defenition for the code at the bottom